# Will I loose my data from windows if I import my account to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: windows, accounts

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and right now it's importing my only account from Windows 7.

I'm wondering: Is it just copying and pasting my account, or is it removing my account from Windows completely, so it will only be in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

It only copies your stuff over, nothing deleted.

Comment: OK! Thank You so Much! I was really worried I screwed something up.